# FirebaseError:Internal Given While Testing Callable Firebase Cloud Functions with Node Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

**Environment** 
Firebase: 9.8.0 
Node: v16.14.2

**Issue** 
I am trying to test a callable Firebase cloud function using a Node.js script using the functions emulator, but I keep getting the following error when running the script in my terminal:

```
error [FirebaseError: internal] {
  code: 'functions/internal',
  customData: undefined,
  details: undefined
}
```

I do not get any more information even when running the script using the verbose output. From my understanding of the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/ErrorCode), there is something wrong server-side where the cloud function is being invoked and failing.

Firebase emulator is working fine and will respond correctly to HTTP requests written with `functions.https.onRequest()`.

Here is my function:

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    if (!context.auth) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
            'while authenticated.');
      }
    console.log( "hello World" );
    console.log( data );
    console.log( context );
    const responseVal = { retval:"Hello World from callable function." };
    console.log( responseVal )
    return responseVal;
});
```

and here is my node.js script (based mostly on the [Firebase guide for calling functions from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#web-version-9_3)):

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable, connectFunctionsEmulator } from 'firebase/functions';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
  measurementId: "..."
};

const app = initializeApp( firebaseConfig );
const functions = getFunctions( app );
connectFunctionsEmulator( functions, "http://localhost", 5001 );

const helloWorld = httpsCallable( functions, 'helloWorld' );
helloWorld( { hello: "hi" } ) 
  .then( (result) => {
    console.log( "worked" )
    const data = result.data;
    console.log( data.retval );
  })
  .catch( (error) => { 
    console.log( "error", error );
    console.log( "code", error.code );
    console.log( "message", error.message );
    console.log( "details", error.details );
  } )
```

Is there something that would cause the function call in my Node script to invoke the onCall function but have it fail?

The same error is given when I try run script with my emulator running and when I run the script without the emulator running. This may be an issue of initailizing my application or connecting my application to the firebase emulator but I am unsure where I have gone wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Specifying the timezone and removing "http://" from the `connectFunctionsEmulator()` function resolved the issue.

```
const app = initializeApp( firebaseConfig );
const functions = getFunctions( app );
connectFunctionsEmulator( functions, "http://localhost", 5001 );
```

Changed to:

```
const app = initializeApp( firebaseConfig );
const functions = getFunctions( app, "us-central1" ); 
connectFunctionsEmulator( functions, "localhost", 5001 );
```

Comment: put me on the right track… I had added local emulators, but one day fogot to actually run it :P